# Can't restoring data from localstorage do not working

Tags: vue.js, local-storage

So that I can't post code to jsfeedle, it's issue with my provider or jsfeedle - it do not allow me to save code. So I post code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <title>test</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
     <input v-model="message" @keyup.enter.native="pressed">
    </div>

</body>

    <script>
        new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {
            message: ''
          },

            created()
              {
                document.onkeydown=function(e)
                  {
                    var key=window.event.keyCode;
                    if(key==113){
                      console.log('F2 pressed save')
                      localStorage.message = this.message;
                      console.log("recovered value: ", this.message)
                    }

                    if(key==115){
                      console.log('F4 restore')
                      // this.message = localStorage.message;
                      this.message = "444";

                    }

                  }

            }

            })

    </script>

</html>
```

The problem that I can't recover saved to localstorage data back by pressing key (F4 in my case).

upd: live example here https://jsbin.com/wiqezuheji/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to save and retrieve variables in the localStorage works a bit different from your attempt. The correct syntax is:

```
// Get something from the localStorage
localStorage.getItem('item_name_here');

// Set something in the localStorage
localStorage.setItem('item_name_here', value);

// Remove something from the localStorage
localStorage.removeItem('item_name_here');

// Clear the entire localStorage
localStorage.clear();
```

So in your case it would be

```
// Saving the message in the localStorage
localStorage.setItem('message', this.message);

// Retrieving the message from the localStorage
this.message = localStorage.getItem('message');
```

For more information you can look [at the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

**Edit**

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/513142/) as an example

And here is a working [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/kocuhakevi/2/edit?html,js,output) example

Comment: Does this code works for you? Could you try run it on jsbin.com on. It's do not works for me. It's not recover value on input field.

Comment: @DmitryBubnenkov I'll try and make a JSFiddle of it. That code does infact work for me since I use it in a number of projects

Comment: @DmitryBubnenkov I have added a JSFiddle and JSBin example to my answer

Comment: T. Dirks, there is issue in my code with `this` keyword. Could you help me to fix it? I create new scope in keypress handler...

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function);
```

try

```
localStorage.setItem('message', this.message);
```

to set in localStorage
and

```
this.message = localStorage.getItem('message');
```

to get from localstorage

Comment: could you jsfeedle to show how it's working. I can't get it works.